# Similiar UPDATE instruction in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Is there an example of a 2-columns table, (x, y - INTEGER), which given instructions:

```
UPDATE tab SET x = y WHERE x != y;
```

```
UPDATE tab SET x = y WHERE 1 = 1 OR (NULL IS NOT NULL);
```

will show different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (x integer, y integer);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (NULL, 1);

/* doesn't update a single row */
UPDATE tab SET x = y WHERE x != y;

TABLE tab;

TABLE tab;
   x    │ y 
════════╪═══
 (null) │ 1
(1 row)

/* updates a row */
UPDATE tab SET x = y WHERE 1 = 1 OR (NULL IS NOT NULL);

TABLE tab;

 x │ y 
═══╪═══
 1 │ 1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for that example.

Answer (score 0):

In the first statement, `x != y` evaluates to true only if `x` and `y` are not `null`s. So if (x,y), are any combination of a value and a `null`, `x` will remain unchanged.

In the second statement, the `where` condition evaluates to true, and can just be omitted altogether - all the `x` values will be updated with their corresponding `y` values.

Comment: Thank you a lot for explaining difference between that two statements!